# Failed login using Python (selenium) - what works with v-on:click="submitForm"?

Tags: python, selenium, login-automation

**Can I use selenium or do I need a different module in order to click this kind of button? and what is the related code please?..... see details as follows and thanks for your help in advance.**

I am a newbie to coding altogether. Slowly learning Python.

Current project is logging into trading website - my code is failing on last button click.

The HTML related to the button includes: **v-on:click="submitForm" :disabled="isSubmit"**

From a quick search this is Vue.js which I am not familiar with.

Ps my very first coding question!

---

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> line 21, in  
> login_button.click()
>  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

---

WRITTEN CODE:

```
from selenium import webdriver

USERNAME = 'XXXXXX'<br>
PASSWORD = 'YYYYYY'

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www.nabtrade.com.au/investor/home')<br>
open_login_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-login')<br>
open_login_button.click()

user_input = driver.find_element_by_id('usernameField')<br>
user_input.send_keys(USERNAME)

password_input = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordField')<br>
password_input.send_keys(PASSWORD)

*login_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn btn-primary btn-block')*<br>
*login_button.click()*
```

NOTE: last two line of code are the ones failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line 21, in
login_button.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

the above **error** is because you are using `find_elements` instead of `find_element`.

```
find_elements
```

will return a list of web element in Selenium Python bindings.

where as

```
find_element
```

returns a single web element.

I see you are using class name with spaces, that is not supported by Selenium-Python, try switching to `xpath` :

Your code should look like this :

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Login']")
login_button.click()
```

Comment: Hi Cruisepandey... I removed the 's' and got a new error, this was due to the spaces in the class name as you pointed out. Switched to xpath and that fixed it. Thanks for your help and I learnt something new. Have an awesome day :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
login_button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('btn btn-primary btn-block')
```

Try using

```
login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-primary btn-block')
```

`find_element_by_class_name` returns a list of web elements, you can not click on a list, only on specific, single element

Comment: Great spot on the 's'. That was causing the original error - I have a new error, however using the xpath suggested by cruisepandey ended up working. Thanks heaps for your help.